# Woocommerce add form-billing template to account form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I got stuck in this issue:

I want to add the form-billing.php in the form-edit-account.php.

After some fileds in the form I included the file with the path "../checkout/form-billing.php" but it return me error failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide col-sm-6">
    <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    <span id="btn-change-pass" class="btn">+ Change your password</span>
</p>

<?php include "../checkout/form-billing.php"; ?>
```

I doesn't understand why it can't find it. I have the file in the folder woocommerce->checkout and the form-edit account is in woocommerce->myaccount

Does it want absolute path?

Comment: check your included file path its must be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the include file path.

else

use below hook action add custom form fields for edit account

```
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_end(  ) { 
    // Add the form
}; 


add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_end', 10, 0 );
```